# Cannot understand the ToolTip ReshowDelay property?

Tags: c#

Recently I went through the `ToolTip` topic. I cannot understand the

> ReshowDelay(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.reshowdelay(v=vs.110).aspx)
>   property.

Can any one explain this with some example?

Comment: _With the ReshowDelay property, you can shorten or lengthen the time that the ToolTip waits before displaying a ToolTip window after a previous ToolTip window is displayed_ what don't you understand?

Comment: do you still have difficulties understanding the use of `ReshowDelay` ?

Answer (score 1):

It does what the documentation says:

> When a ToolTip window is currently being displayed and the user moves the pointer to another control that displays a ToolTip window, the value of the ReshowDelay property is used before showing the ToolTip for the new control.

Example:

Set the following values:

```
// Set up the delays for the ToolTip.
toolTip1.InitialDelay = 3000;
toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500;
```

Make a WinForm with 2 `Button`s and a `ToolTip`.

The set the tooltip:

```
// Set up the ToolTip text for the Button and Checkbox.
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button1, "It's me!");
toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button2, "me again!");
```

Now move the cursor upon the `button1` and you will see that it takes about 3 seconds for the tool tip to pop up.

Now move from `button1` directly to `button2` and you will see that it takes only half a second for the second tooltip to pop up.

**EDIT:**

this will only work if the buttons are close to each other, so that you can reach the next button in a very short time, like in these pictures:

[image] [image]

Apparently the first pop up has still to be visible when the cursor reaches the second button, otherwise the next tooltip popup is not treated as a **subsequent** one and the normal `InitialDelay` is applied again.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.reshowdelay(v=vs.110).aspx) says to this point:

> The ToolTip window from the previous control must still be displayed in order for the delay specified in the ReshowDelay property to be used

Comment: Hi Monk, I tried your code....but "button1" and "button2" takes the same "3 seconds" time to pop up.....

Comment: @PaviK I made an edit to shed more light on this case. Have a look